# Deselect item in multiitem listbox with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview, listbox

I am trying to deselect item (once selected) when user will click on the item in listbox.

I have a script which is deselecting the item on user click but that is happening even when the item is selected for first time as well.

This is what I have:

JS:

```
 function deselect()
          {
              var list = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCity.ClientID%>');
              var listLength = list.options.length; 
              for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
                  if (list.options[i].selected) {
                      list.selectedIndex = -1;
                  }
              }
          }
```

And the html:

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="ddlCity" CssClass="formfield" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCity"
                DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="CityID" SelectionMode="Multiple" onclick="deselect();"
                OnDataBound="DropDownList3_DataBound"></asp:ListBox>
```

How can I edit that JS to deselect the value once the value is selected, but when user selects the value for first time the value to be selected?

Comment: Just add list.options[i].selectedIndex = -1 instead of list.selectedIndex = -1 as my answer

Comment: If you want the user to only be able to select 1 item at a time, simply remove `SelectionMode="Multiple"`. If you then also want the user to be able to unselect the 1 item, work with the `onclick` and have javascript remember which item was selected last time the user clicked. If the one currently clicked equals the one clicked last time, unselect it.